# How to chain Promises? — clarification needed

Tags: node.js, promise

Trying to use Promises instead of [caolan's async library](https://github.com/caolan/async), I'm struggling with completely different approach. A little clarification is highly appreciated.

Let's say I'm registering User with [Sequezlie](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize) library. To do this I need:

1. Create user oject
2. Create dependent object Folder
3. Return result to client

Sequezlie use promises for all CRUD-operations. And User.register is a promisifed shortcut to `User.create(...)`.

```
user =
  email: req.body.email
  name : req.body.name

createFolder = (user)->
  new Promise (resolve, reject)->
    Folder
      .build(title: "untitled", UserId: user.id)
      .save()
      .then (folder)-> resolve folder
      .catch (err)-> reject err

# register
User
  .register(user, req.body.password)
  .then(createFolder(user))
  .then (folder)->
    console.log "User with Folder is created"
    res.send 201
```

At this time Folder is created, but createFolder() has no access to `user` object. What I'm doing wrong? Which is the better way to chain Promises and access it's results in each other?

FYI, I'm using [then/promise](https://github.com/then/promise) implementation.

Thanks.

Comment: Does Folder return a promise? Because it looks like it.

Comment: @ slebetman ...yes, and If I've got your idea, function should look like this? `createFolder = (user)-> Folder.build(title: "untitled", UserId: user.id).save()`

Comment: Is this coffeescript? I don't know coffee but can give you a plain js answer

Comment: @slebetman you are right, plain js version would be ```var createFolder = function(user) {
  return Folder.build({
    title: "untitled",
    UserId: user.id
  }).save();
};
```

Comment: a) Don't use the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572) (in `createFolder`) b) I think you'll want to pass a callback to `then`?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've defined a function `createUser` that accepts a parameter `user`.

I suspect (though it's hard to tell from your code) that this is *not* meant to be the same object `user` declared in the outer scope. You pass that to `register`, and that returns a different object (wrapped in a promise) representing the user. Let's call that object `registeredUser` to avoid confusion:

```
User
  .register(user, req.body.password)
  .then((registeredUser) -> createFolder(registeredUser))
  .then (folder)-> ...
```

We can write that more succinctly:

```
User
  .register(user, req.body.password)
  .then(createFolder)
  .then (folder)-> ...
```

The difference is that we are not calling `createFolder` - we're just passing it to `then` so it acts directly as the handler function for the successful resolution of the promise returned by `register`, i.e. it will be called by `then` when the user is registered.

**Update**

You asked in the comments about accessing the results of multiple previous promises, further back in the chain. Just start another chain inside the previous handler:

```
User.register(user, req.body.password).then((registeredUser) ->
  createFolder(registeredUser).then (folder) ->
    # do more stuff here, or just return an object
    {
      folder: folder
      user: registeredUser
    }
).then (all) ->
  console.log all
```

By returning an object from the inner `then`, that becomes the result passed back to the outer chain, so `all` is the object with `folder` and `user` properties.

Comment: Thank you, I've figured it out. Wha't about chaining more the 2 functions? For example if in 3th chain (promise) I need to get the resolve (result) of 1st?

Comment: Notice there are [many ways to access results from previous promises](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28250680/1048572). The [nesting](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28250687/1048572) presented here is just one of them.

Answer (score 1):

Sequelize queries seems to return promises. In which case you don't need to create your own promise objects - just use the ones returned by sequelize:

```
function createFolder (user) {
    // assuming the following returns a promise
    return Folder.build(title: "untitled", UserId: user.id).save();
}
```

Then you can chain it like this:

```
User.register(user, req.body.password)
    .then(createFolder) // <------------ note!!
    .then function (folder) {
        console.log("User with Folder is created");
        res.send(201);
    }
```

> note!!: We pass createFolder instead of calling it!
>   That's because the .then() will call it when .register() completes.

Comment: I think the problem is that `createFolder` expects a `user` object that has an `id` property. In the OP's code (and your version) it is being passed the wrong object.

Comment: Ah, yes. Assuming `User.register` returns the object `createFolder` needs, it should just be passed as-is rather than called. Good catch.